# How to change Oracle user password without showing the actual password on screen?

Tags: oracle

Is there a way you can change Oracle user password without showing the actual password on the screen? I understand that you can execute `ALTER USER user_name IDENTIFIED BY new_password;` but this will show the password on screen.

My organization practices split-password for administrator password and two person would need to key in the password. How do I allow them to key in the password without any of them viewing any portion of the password?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this with the SQL*Plus [`password`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve029.htm#i2676330) command.

To change the current user's password, just type `password` and you'll get the usual prompt.

```
$ sqlplus foo/foo123
...
SQL> password
Changing password for FOO
Old password:
New password:
Retype new password:
Password changed
```

You can also use `password username` to change another user's password (if you're logged on with sufficient privileges - you need to be dba I believe).

SQL Developer also allows you to do that. Just type `password` and execute, and you'll get a password change popup. Or expand the "Other users" branch, right-click on the account that needs a change and select the "Edit user" menu.

Comment: Well, you learn something new every day! +1

Comment: Hi, I have a quick question. If we forgot the previous password, we can execute ALTER USER user_name IDENTIFIED BY new_password; and then execute the password command again. Am I correct? Thanks.

Comment: Yes unless you've got minimum password age policies in place (not sure how those work). If you log in as dba, the `password other_user` mode doesn't ask for the old password, so that's an option too.